# Local-global principal for modules: simple example

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In commutative algebra, a very basic theorem which we study in localizations is the following.

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $M=0$.
2. The localization $M_{P}=0$ for every prime ideal of $R$.
3. The localization $M_P=0$ for every maximal ideal of $R$.

The theorem is termed as of type local-global nature; but I didn't understand the philosophical comment.

**Q.** Is there a simple example illustrating above theorem? (For example, is there an easier equation over a ring, which is difficult to solve within the ring, but easy to solve in the localizations and conclude about solvability of the equation?

Comment: When $R$ is a Dedekind domain, all its localizations $R_P$ are DVR, hence PID — which is a very nice property.

Comment: Not sure quite what you are after here, but e.g. the above theorem immediately implies that a module homomorphism is surjective if and only if it is surjective in all its localizations; surjection of a module homomorphisms over a local ring can be made easier by Nakayama's Lemma.